# Cannot find AwaitableTriggerDagRunOperator anymore for Airflow [Python]

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm working on a python project using Airflow. In the project there is no `requirements.txt` file so I simply installed the latest version of the libraries by putting their name inside a `requirement.txt` file and I've been trying to make it work.

The import which is causing trouble is this one:

```py
from airflow_common.operators.awaitable_trigger_dag_run_operator import (
    AwaitableTriggerDagRunOperator,
)
```

Looking online for `AwaitableTriggerDagRunOperator` I cannot find any documentation about this operator, the only result that comes up is [this](https://github.com/cherkavi/cheat-sheet/blob/master/airflow.md) page where another person is using it and this person is importing it in the same way I am.

I guess that the project was developed with a very old version of Airflow and things have changed quite a bit. Here is the version that I have installed.

```bash
$ pip freeze | awk '/airflow/'
airflow-commons==0.0.67
apache-airflow==2.5.3
apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes==6.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql==1.4.0
apache-airflow-providers-ftp==3.3.1
apache-airflow-providers-http==4.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-imap==3.1.1
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite==3.3.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an official Apache Airflow document, so it's hard to say why this is used as an import. There is no Apache Airflow library called `airflow_common` This is most likely something written by this user. You should raise an issue and ask this question on this github repo here

https://github.com/cherkavi/cheat-sheet/issues

Comment: Yup, the project was vast and weirdly linked using Bazel, a `find . -name "airflow_common" solved the problem. The folder was left behind during a migration.